# How do I query distinct values within multiple sub record sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Below is an example record set.

I would like to query the "Value" once each time that it changes. For instance, I would like Row #1, 9, 14, 26, 28, 37 & 50.

I have tried using SELECT DISTINCT, but this does not work because the "Value" column has repeating values (ie. Row #1 & 14).

I have been searching for awhile now and have not found a solution. Please let me know if you have one! thanks!

```
Row Value   Time Stamp
1   1916    2013-10-01 00:05:00
2   1916    2013-10-01 00:06:00
3   1916    2013-10-01 00:07:00
4   1916    2013-10-01 00:08:00
5   1916    2013-10-01 00:09:00
6   1916    2013-10-01 00:18:00
7   1916    2013-10-01 00:21:00
8   1916    2013-10-01 00:22:00
9   2272    2013-10-01 00:36:00
10  2272    2013-10-01 00:37:00
11  2272    2013-10-01 00:40:00
12  2272    2013-10-01 00:41:00
13  2272    2013-10-01 00:42:00
14  1916    2013-10-01 00:43:00
15  1916    2013-10-01 00:55:00
16  1916    2013-10-01 00:56:00
17  1916    2013-10-01 00:58:00
18  1916    2013-10-01 00:59:00
19  1916    2013-10-01 01:02:00
20  1916    2013-10-01 01:03:00
21  1916    2013-10-01 01:05:00
22  1916    2013-10-01 01:06:00
23  1916    2013-10-01 01:07:00
24  1916    2013-10-01 01:08:00
25  1916    2013-10-01 01:09:00
26  1860    2013-10-01 01:20:00
27  1860    2013-10-01 01:21:00
28  2272    2013-10-01 01:22:00
29  2272    2013-10-01 01:23:00
30  2272    2013-10-01 01:24:00
31  2272    2013-10-01 01:25:00
32  2272    2013-10-01 01:26:00
33  2272    2013-10-01 01:27:00
34  2272    2013-10-01 01:28:00
35  2272    2013-10-01 01:29:00
36  2272    2013-10-01 01:30:00
37  1917    2013-10-01 01:31:00
38  1917    2013-10-01 01:36:00
39  1917    2013-10-01 01:37:00
40  1917    2013-10-01 01:39:00
41  1917    2013-10-01 01:42:00
42  1917    2013-10-01 01:43:00
43  1917    2013-10-01 01:47:00
44  1917    2013-10-01 01:48:00
45  1917    2013-10-01 01:49:00
46  1917    2013-10-01 01:54:00
47  1917    2013-10-01 01:55:00
48  1917    2013-10-01 01:56:00
49  1917    2013-10-01 02:01:00
50  1860    2013-10-01 02:02:00
51  1860    2013-10-01 02:03:00
52  1860    2013-10-01 02:05:00
53  1860    2013-10-01 02:07:00
54  1860    2013-10-01 02:08:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most recent version of SQL Server, you can use the `lag()` function.  Assuming you have an older version, you can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
select Value, TimeStamp
from (select t1.*,
             (select top 1 value
              from t t2
              where t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
              order by timestamp desc
             ) as prevvalue
      from t t1
     ) t1
where prevvalue is null or prevvalue <> value;
```

Comment: That's only available in the **2012** and newer versions of SQL Server, though - not in 2008 ...

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am having trouble implementing this. Mainly because to get the original data-set (posted above), I was already using a  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TimeStamp] ORDER BY [TimeStamp]) as num in order to get only 1 record per minute. Also, there is a-lot of t's. In particular, what does this t.timestamp in where "t2.timestamp < t.timestamp" refer to? Is that the t in the "from t t2".

Comment: So, what I did was take the my original query and make it into a CTE and then I am implementing your query with that CTE.

Comment: I was able to get this to work. I figured out t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp. Now to improve the execution time...

Comment: @Mausimo . . . For improved execution time, add an index on `t(timestamp, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently cant leave comments yet...

```
where t2.timestamp < t.timestamp
```

should be

```
where t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
```

The above using common table expression

```
;with cte as (select t1.*,
             (select top 1 value
              from table1 t2
              where t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
              order by timestamp desc
             ) as prevvalue
      from table1 t1
     ) 
select Value, TimeStamp
from cte
where prevvalue is null 
or prevvalue <> value
```

Comment: Yes, I got this working. I Was able to figure out t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp. Thanks for the help though!