# Count value variation from 0 to 1 in mysql table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a column with two columns. one is `TIMESTAMP` and the other `DIGITAL_BIT`.

The value digital bit can be either 0 or 1 and changes a few times during the day. Every minute of the day is stored in this table. I would need to read somehow how many times a day this value changed from 0 to 1.

Is it possible to make a query that returns the count of this changes? What I have in mind is something like this:

```
select * from mytable where digital_bit = 1 and digital_bit (of previous row) = 0 order by timestamp
```

Can this be done with a query or do i have to process all data in my program?

Thanks

SAMPLE

```
timestamp | digital_bit

100000    | 0
100001    | 0
100002    | 1
100003    | 1
100004    | 0
100005    | 1
100006    | 0
100007    | 0
100008    | 1
```

the above should return 3 because for 3 times the value digital passed from 0 to 1. i need to count how often the value digital CHANGES from 0 to 1.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, its quite hard to understand. Currently the way I'm understanding it is that you cannot count these changes unless you record it somewhere every time the `digital_bit` is  changed.

Comment: thanks, updated the question with a sample.

Comment: I saw a great query for doing exactly this yesterday, will try and track down the question

Comment: With this example the count of changes will be 5 (correct me if i am wrong). Writing procedure seems better option.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846719/how-do-i-query-distinct-values-within-multiple-sub-record-sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. This will get you a count of how many times digital_bit switched from 0 to 1 (in your example, this will return 3).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mytable curr
WHERE curr.digital_bit = 1
AND (
    SELECT digital_bit
    FROM mytable prev
    WHERE prev.timestamp < curr.timestamp
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
) = 0
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21274/3/0)

*(Original answer relied on the timestamps being sequential: e.g. no jumps from 100001 to 100003. Answer has now been updated not to have that restriction.)*

Comment: this is not guaranteed.. sometimes it can fire a few seconds earlier, sometimes a few seconds later.. take the timestamp column ONLY to set the proper order..

Comment: @sharkyenergy updated to take this into account. ANY change from 0 in one row to 1 in the following row will now be counted.

Comment: youre the king! :) thank you very much! marking as accepted. fast and simple (had to add a where clause to limit the rows)

Comment: @sharkyenergy:  Count is 3. It should be 5.

Comment: suresh, 3 is correct. i do only need the change from 0 to 1, not from 1 to 0.

Comment: How does this perform with the large number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you have one query every minute. So you have no problem with performance.

You can add flag:

```
timestamp | digital_bit | changed

100000    | 0           | 0
100001    | 0           | 0
100002    | 1           | 1
100003    | 1           | 0
100004    | 0           | 1
100005    | 1           | 1
100006    | 0           | 1
100007    | 0           | 0
100008    | 1           | 1
```

And make check before insert:

```
SELECT digital_bit
FROM table
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and if `digital_bit` is different  insert new row with flag.

And then you just can take `COUNT` of flags:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE DATE BETWEEN (start, end)
      AND changed = 1
```

Hope will see in answers better solution.

Comment: That should be `WHERE DATE BETWEEN (start, end)` and not `BEETWIN` ;-)

Comment: Yes, don't like that word:)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't likely to be efficient with a lot of data, but you can get all the rows and calculate a sequence number for them, then do the same again but with the sequence number offset by 1. Then join the 2 lots together where those calculated sequence numbers match but the first one has a digital bit of 0 and the other a digital bit of 1:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT mytable.timestamp, mytable.digital_bit, @aCount1:=@aCount1+1 AS SeqCount
    FROM mytable 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @aCount1:=1) sub1
    ORDER BY timestamp
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT mytable.timestamp, mytable.digital_bit, @aCount2:=@aCount2+1 AS SeqCount
    FROM mytable 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @aCount2:=0) sub1
    ORDER BY timestamp
) b
ON a.SeqCount = b.SeqCount
AND a.digital_bit = 0
AND b.digital_bit = 1
```

EDIT - alternative solution and I would be interested to see how this performs. It avoids the need for adding a sequence number and also avoids a correlated sub query:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT curr.timestamp, MAX(curr2.timestamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
    FROM mytable curr
    INNER JOIN mytable curr2
    ON curr.timestamp > curr2.timestamp
    AND curr.digital_bit = 1
    GROUP BY curr.timestamp
) Sub1
INNER JOIN mytable curr
ON Sub1.MaxTimeStamp = curr.timestamp
AND curr.digital_bit = 0
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately with a 1500000 rows this takes forever. upvoted you anyway.. maybe it suseful for somebody else

Comment: No problem. If you only need a days records then you could check the timestamp within each of the sub queries (limits it to only 1440 records from each sub query which should be fairly fast). An alternative you be to add a sequence number to the table which is indexed and can be updated when required (possibly in a trigger)

Comment: @sharkyenergy - added an alternative solution. I would be interested to see how it performs

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from: [How do I query distinct values within multiple sub record sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846719/how-do-i-query-distinct-values-within-multiple-sub-record-sets)

```
select count(*)
from (select t1.*,
             (select digital_bit
              from table t2
              where t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp
              order by timestamp desc LIMIT 1
             ) as prevvalue
      from table t1
     ) t1
where prevvalue <> digital_bit and digital_bit = 1;
```

Comment: sorry, somewhat confused here: t1 is declared in the query, and t2 is supposed to be my own table? right?

Comment: `table` is your table. It gets referenced twice and named `t1` and `t2`. The only bit you should need to replace is `table` with your table name.

Comment: sorry thats for sql-server, updating answer for mysql now. -updated now (using LIMIT instead of TOP)

Comment: good solution but another guy posted a better one! thank you anyway and upvoted you

Comment: ahh I misread the question, didn't realise you only wanted the 0 -> 1 changes

Answer (score 1):

IF you have a result once per minte, you can simple join the table with itself, and
use timestamp+1 as well as leftbit != rightbit as join condition.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/791c0/6

ALL Changes:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  test a
INNER JOIN
  test b
ON 
  a.digital_bit != b.digital_bit
  AND b.timestamp = a.timestamp+1;
```

Changes from 0 to 1

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  test a
INNER JOIN
  test b
ON 
  a.digital_bit = 0 AND
  a.digital_bit != b.digital_bit
  AND b.timestamp = a.timestamp+1;
```

Changes from 1 to 0

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  test a
INNER JOIN
  test b
ON 
  a.digital_bit = 1 AND
  a.digital_bit != b.digital_bit
  AND b.timestamp = a.timestamp+1;
```

Comment: good anser. i already accpeted another one. upvoted yours as otehrs might need it! thank you anyway

Comment: This has the same problem mine originally had, where it relies on there not being any jumps e.g. from 100001 to 100003, which OP said there might be.

Comment: @Shai Op said: `Every minute of the day is stored in this table`, so no gaps. (Assuming the timestamp beeing minutes as in the example provided)

Comment: ah, in the comments of your post.